# yii2 generate th tag instead td in gridview rows

Tags: gridview, yii2

In order to use a external responsive table layout I need to insert first column of rows with `th` tag instead `td` in yii2 gridview. Is there a way to set tag of columns in yii2 gridview? It is possible to set it in columns of `beforeHeader` section stated [here](http://demos.krajee.com/grid) but did not see same property for ordinary columns.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Yii already renders a `th` tag for the header cells. Maybe some other extension you're using is overriding this? Anyway, you can customise it by extending the `yii\grid\column` and overriding the `renderHeaderCell()` [method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/grid/Column.php#L81), but you should work out what is overriding the header cells first!

Comment: I thought same solution and search for short way but it seems tag is not parametrized for data cells. Thanks..

Comment: No, the tag is hard-coded into the method and cannot be changed by passing parameters.